# How to call the event of usercontrol in page of aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls

I have created the usercontrol. There is event :

```
public event System.EventHandler MemberSelectionChanged;
```

I have called this event in aspx page like this(given below). It working fine. Is there any other way to call the user control event in aspx page.

```
this.ucMemberList.MemberSelectionChanged += new EventHandler(MemberList_MemberSelectionChanged);
```

Comment: Can you explain *other ways*; what exactly are you looking for? For instance, how else do you want to call it?

Comment: instead of writing public event System.EventHandler MemberSelectionChanged; Is there any other way to call that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shalni, if under "calling" you mean assigning handler to an event, so you did it right way. Not aware of other ways.

Comment: can u help me:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283922/how-to-trigger-click-event-of-a-button-in-usercontrol-from-contentpage