# How to Trigger Click Event of a Button in UserControl from ContentPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, eventhandler

I have a ShoppingCart `UserControl` on `MasterPage`. I have a following functionality:
User adds item to the cart. after clicking the `button` "`Complete Sale`" in `UserControl` the page is redirected to "`CustomerInfo.aspx`" and after filling the Customer information and clicking on submit which is on CustomerInfo.aspx page i want to call the "`Complete Sale`" `click event` of UserControl from "`Customerinfo.aspx`" page.

**Customerinfo.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bool val=false;
            int retVal = 0;
            CustomerBiz objCust = new CustomerBiz();

            objCust.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
            objCust.LastName = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
            objCust.Phone = txtPhone.Text.Trim();
            objCust.Email = txtEmail.Text.Trim();
            if (hdnCustomerID!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnCustomerID.Value) && hdnCustomerID.Value!="0")
                objCust.CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(hdnCustomerID.Value);
            else
                objCust.CustomerID =0;
            retVal = objCust.AddCustomerInfo();
            if (retVal > 0)
            {
                //success     
                UserControl uch = Page.Master.FindControl("shpCart") as UserControl;
                Button lnkCheckOut=uch.FindControl("lnkCheckOut") as Button;
                lnkCheckOut.Text = "Found in Customer.aspx";
                //lnkCheckOut.Click += new EventHandler(lnkCheckOut.);
                lnkCheckOut.Text = "You Clicked";//Here Text of button in UserControl changes but how to call the ClickEvent of this button in Customerinfo.aspx page ?

                // completeBtn.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
                Response.Redirect("Devices.aspx", true);
            }
            else
            { 
                //fail
            }
       }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Here the `Button` text changes in `UserControl`. But i am not able to call the `Click event` of this `button` from `CustomerInfo.aspx` (ContentPage) any suggestions?

Comment: you will have to raise event...

Comment: i know i need to create an EventHandler in User Control but how to use will you please elaborate? so that this code works..As i explained UserControl in added to MasterPage and after filling customerinfo(ContentPage) i need to call the Click event of UserControl